# Install4J and filechooser via bean info or action

Tags: install4j

I'm trying out Install4J and am creating a custom action.  I would like to create a field that gets exposed by install4J to have a button for a file chooser and select from the installation directory tree.  For example, the "delete files and directories" standard action has a property called "files and directories" that, when clicked, will expose an Edit button [...] that pops up an "Edit Files" dialog.  I want this to occur in one of my fields in my custom action.  I can't seem to get this exposed-- either from the action or the beaninfo class.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `ManyFeaturesAction` in samples/customCode/src, it shows a couple of file properties. Basically, you define a property of type `java.io.File` and call

```
addPropertyDescriptor(FilePropertyDescriptor.create("propertyName", 
    getBeanClass(),
    "File property",
    "A packaged file or directory",
    FileSelectionMode.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES
));
```

in the BeanInfo class.